# When is rlm preferred over lm and vice versa? Why R Square should not be considered for models built using rlm?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, lm, rlm

Both **lm** and **rlm** are used for multiple linear regression. **rlm** stands for robust multiple linear regression and so is considered to treat outliers in a better way.

How exactly does **rlm** and **lm** work? Which is better?

In what circumstances **rlm** is preferred over lm and vice versa?

Why is there no significance for R square parameter for the model built using **rlm**?

And, Are there any alternative methods other than **lm** and **rlm** for multiple linear regression in R?

Comment: so will it be a problem if we use RLM when there are no outliers? Sorry, but can you provide more clarity on when exactly to use RLM and LM?

Comment: Can you also enlighten me a little on QR factorisation and how it can be done in R?

Comment: okay, thanks; have a nice day. i have upvoted your answer.